# How to disable multiple form submission in Jquery from onload() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a `JSP` with `onload` function in form. This enable JavaScript to submit the form. I require to submit form once irrespective of multiple form submission in form of F5 (refresh).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my JSP</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onload() {
                alert("This form should submit once");
                document.form.submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="javascript:onloadEvent()">
```

Problem is on back button my page goes back and upon submit from previous page it is routed again. I cant change in my previous page as it is from another application.

PS: My `JSP` doesn't have a submit button. It submit the form with `onload()` function. Its a redirect page from one application to another.

Comment: The simplest solution would be: Don't do this. You are obviously trying to solve a bigger problem, but instead of asking about that problem, you are asking about your perceived (but wrong) solution. Why do you think you need this redirect page? Why don't you link directly from the original page to the target page?

Comment: the source applictation is unable to handle multiple request. So in order to create a filter for receiving request . It should be triggered only once. i know its a tedious and wrong from architecture perspective. But I am stuck for with change to be made in this page.  Appreciate if anyone has a solution to this.